# "Message: Call to a member function post() on null" in helper

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I get an error in controller and i added construct func and i add get_instance in helper but i get this error .

`Helper added autoload.php`

I've tried looking stackoverflow and I couldn't find anything

```
//in helper
function postvalue($name){

    $ci =& get_instance();
    return $ci->input->post($name);
}

//in controller

          $isexist = Process_admin::find([
            "root_username"=>postvalue("username"),
          "root_password"=>md5(postvalue("password"))

        ]);
```

***Error message*** :

[image]

I was waiting for the output as a post from the dire but I get an error

Comment: That suggests that `$ci` is coming back as null.

Comment: There is syntax error, it must be $ci = &get_instance(); .

Comment: @droopsnoot maybe , how can i fix it ?

Comment: @samratshakya now tried but no change

Comment: @droopsnoot i tried `print_r(var_dumo($ci))` and not null

Comment: @owoki I think  `$this->input->post()` must work.  To post you don't have to use get_instance.

Comment: what you are doing should work. also, is `$this->input->post()` so long that you need a helper for it ;) ?

Comment: @Alex oov i get very bad error. I use `$this->input->post()` in controller but dont work i error again (null)

Comment: null isn't an error. perhaps your post data isn't getting to your controller to begin with.i would start there as this is the recommended way of getting post variables and has been used in countless projects without issue.

Comment: i see my variables with $_POST. I delete and reinstall codeigniter and get an error `Message: Undefined property: Welcome::$input` i only add `$this->input->post()` @Alex

Comment: very odd. paste the entire controller on https://pastebin.com/ and give us the link to check out

Answer (score 0):

You can directly access name value by $name in helper function

Comment: in controller `$this->input->post()` doesnt work. i get `Message: Undefined property: Welcome::$input`